# XSLT namespace prefixes throwing processor error

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to combine some XML files and keep the namespaces between them separate, and am running into some problems. Everything I've been able to find on SO looks like this (XSLT):

```
<xsl:for-each select="sbn:fieldName">
   <xsl:element name="sbn:{name()}">
      <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
   </xsl:element>
</xsl:for-each>
```

I want to preserve the `sbn:` namespace prefix in the output, and this works (at least, it shows up in the result document), but despite this, the processor throws a bunch of warnings that `sbn:` is an invalid element name...despite the fact the the element name actually winds up correctly in the output as `sbn:fieldName`.

Is there other way to do this? I don't want to have the `xmlns` attribute on every element. I'm using Oxygen and Saxon6.5.5 as the processor, though I get the same error on every other processor I've tried (Xalan and the libxslt Mac command-line version).

(You might ask: if the output is fine, why do I care? Good question! I'm running the transformation on a small file in Oxygen now, but the goal is to transform a million-line XML file and do it from the command line using `xsltproc` so that I don't have the memory overhead of Oxygen, since I'll need all the memory I can get to run the transformation.)

**Edit**: more details.

Here's a trimmed down version of the file I'm trying to work on.

```
<collection xmlns="http://www.example.com/ns/foo">
    <record>
        <fieldName>
            <subA>some text</subA>
            <subB>more text</subB>
        </fieldName>
    </record>
</collection>
```

And a trimmed-down version of the stylesheet, showing the problem.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
   xmlns:sbn="http://www.example.com/ns/foo"
   xmlns:bar="http://www.example.com/ns/bar"
   version="1.0">

   <xsl:template match="//sbn:record">
    <xsl:for-each select="sbn:fieldName/node()">
       <xsl:element name="sbn:{local-name()}">
          <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
       </xsl:element>
    </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This gives the xsltproc error: `runtime error: file tiny.xslt line 8 element element
xsl:element: The effective name 'sbn:' is not a valid QName.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the problem is that you are using `sbn:fieldName/node()` - that matches also the text nodes, that have no name - hence the error.

This works for me:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
   xmlns:sbn="http://www.example.com/ns/foo"
   xmlns:bar="http://www.example.com/ns/bar"
   version="1.0">

   <xsl:template match="//sbn:record">
    <xsl:for-each select="sbn:fieldName/*">
       <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
          <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
       </xsl:element>
    </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This gets it, thanks! (I did have to change the element name to `sbn:{name()}`, but that's no big deal.) I had just forgotten what a non-sensical language XSLT is, where `*` selects less than `node()`.

Answer (score 0):

The `name()` function returns the name of a node *with its prefix*, so in this case `sbn:{name()}` is evaluating to `sbn:sbn:fieldName`.  Instead you should use this, if you want to make sure that the prefix `sbn:` is used in the output:

```
<xsl:element name="sbn:{local-name()}">
```

or either of the following, if you want to reuse whatever prefix was used in the input:

```
<xsl:element name="{name()}">
```

or

```
<xsl:copy>
  <!-- (Whatever content you want) -->
</xsl:copy>
```

Comment: Hmm...`local-name()` still gives the error. It looks like there's no difference between the output of `name` and `local-name` if I just do a `value-of` on them.

Comment: That's odd. Upon re-reading your question I see that your reason for doing this is to remove the `xmlns` attribute (which isn't actually an attribute). If that's the reason, then I think you're going about it the wrong way. Could you show us a larger example of your XSLT and some of the example input, plus the current output that has the `xmlns` declarations you want to avoid?

Comment: Thank you. I believe that MiMo has identified the cause of the error, but I'm still not sure what you're trying to achieve with this XSLT. Where is this statement: "I don't want to have the xmlns attribute on every element" involved this XSLT? Changing the nodes to have namespace prefixes will not eliminate the need to have namespace declarations.

Comment: Yes, MiMo's answer fixed the problem. The way I was trying earlier I could get it to output `<sbn:subA>`, but only if it included the xmlns attribute: `<sbn:subA xmlns="http://www.example.com/ns/foo">`. The result file is for hand-editing, so I didn't want the namespace URIs cluttering the file. Thanks for your help!